# CSS Background Image Trouble

Tags: html, css, web, background

html:

```
<div id="Home"></div>
```

css:

```
#Home {
position: relative;
background: url("../Pictures/GoodAssTunes.jpg") ;
height: 800px;
width: 100%;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -8px;
z-index: 1;
background-size: 100%;
```

}

But it wont display for some reason. I've tried it with `background:` and `background-image:` with the shorthand and just `url("GoodAssTunes.jpg")`. But it doens't work.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, are you sure your image is in the spot you say it's in? Alternatively, have you opened it up to see if the image is corrupt?

Comment: Try looking in  Firebug, to see if the image is coming up as a 404

Comment: code is good! Check the case as sometimes CSS can be sensitive to filename formatting

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JD2ft/[It works fine see](http://jsfiddle.net/JD2ft/)

No problem check with Pictures/GoodAssTunes.jpg

```
  #Home {
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150") ;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Open Google Crome**

rightclick open *view page source* or *Inspect element*

and see the link

it should open the image